# Create a build job for sample cucumber ruby project

Tags: ruby, jenkins, cucumber

I am trying to create a build job for my cucumber test in mac. However its throwing error. Not sure what i am doing wrong. I can run my tests using this in Terminal:

```
bundle exec cucumber -t @tests
```

in Jenkins "Execute Batch commands" section i have added below:
    bundle install
    bundle exec cucumber -t @tests

I am getting this below errors in my Jenkins Console Output:

```
Started by user anonymous
Building in workspace /Users/MacPro/.jenkins/workspace/build_job_name
[tests_build] $ cmd /c call /var/folders/fx/m8ltp5dx17lbmqpgpwlc9ps00000gn/T/hudson6634803463309653425.bat
FATAL: command execution failed
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "cmd" (in directory "/Users/MacPro/.jenkins/workspace/tests_build"): error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1047)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:244)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:216)
    at hudson.Launcher$LocalLauncher.launch(Launcher.java:815)
    at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.start(Launcher.java:381)
    at hudson.tasks.CommandInterpreter.perform(CommandInterpreter.java:95)
    at hudson.tasks.CommandInterpreter.perform(CommandInterpreter.java:64)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:782)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.build(Build.java:205)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:162)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:534)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1738)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:410)
    Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:184)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:130)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1028)
    ... 15 more
Build step 'Execute Windows batch command' marked build as failure
An attempt to send an e-mail to empty list of recipients, ignored.
Finished: FAILURE
```

Need help to resolve this.

Comment: I have figured out this issue.... :)   Thanks

Comment: Can you please create an answer and accept it?  This question shows up on answers:0 queries and wastes people's time. Thank you.